# Collection as Symfony Form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a collection of entities called FooCollection. This collection is build from a API response. I don't use doctrine. The entities are instance of class Foo and each hold a class named Bar. I generate in the template a formular list like:

```
<form>
    <ul>
    {% for foo in fooCollection %}
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="foo[{{foo.id}}]" value="1"> <label>{{foo.bar.title}}</label></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

Is it possible to use Symfony2 Forms to create this form list and how can I do that?

Here are the example entities and collections:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    private $bar;
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setBar(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    private $title;

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}

class FooCollection extends \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
{
}
```

Comment: For symfony 2 form making list using entities you can try this if you are using form Builder: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: From the documentation: A special ChoiceType field that's designed to load options from a Doctrine entity. I don't use doctrine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "choice" field type for dropdowns.

Simply SELECT the instances of `Foo` into an array, and pass this into the `choices` option of the ChoiceType to populate the dropdown.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

Comment: This is not a drop down, it is a ul list.